# Simple function with for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm stuck in a very stupid point while reading Numeric Analysis.

So I have the following program in python. And I can't figure why I get these results.

Where do I use the `i` in `heron(x,y)` to get these results?

Because only the first one makes sense for me. Why are the numbers decreasing if the i isn't used at all at the function?

```
def heron(x,y):
    x=(x+y/x)*0.5
    return x

x=1
y=2
for i in range(5):
   x=heron(x,y)
   print('Approximation of square root : %.16f'%x)
```

And the results:

```
Approximation of square root :1.5000000000000000
Approximation of square root :1.4166666666666665
Approximation of square root :1.4142156862745097
Approximation of square root :1.4142135623746899
Approximation of square root :1.4142135623730949
```

Edit: The code was given by my professor in class and I guess the only use of it was to explain few basic things of Python?

Comment: Because the value of `x` is changing within your loop.

Comment: Don't use global variable names for input arguments for `heron`

Comment: @kiran.koduru what do you mean?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What is it meant to do?

Comment: Each iteration through your loop returns the value from `heron` function to the name `x`, which the altered value is then passed to the `heron` function again, as many times as your loop.

Comment: @Neo Just a guess, but I think the OP wants to implement [Heron's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for approximating a square root. It is a common exercise in early computer science courses.

Comment: @David Zemens but how is it changing? Does the i replace the x in the loop?

Comment: No, `i` just tells the program *how many times* to loop. `x` is changing because you're assigning the return value of `hereon` function to the name `x` within the loop.

Comment: @kiran.koduru I'm pretty sure that's not true.  I tested a similar function in interactive mode `def foo(x):` `x = x**2` `return x` and it doesn't mutate the value of a global `x`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you are correct. I will  delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
for i in range(5):
```

only means:

> Do the following five times.

The actual work is done in

```
x = heron(x,y)
```

which uses `x` as part of the arguments of `heron` and assigns the changed value back to it. So while `y` stays unchanged, `x` is changed with each call to `heron`. The changed `x` is then used as an argument to the next call.

**Edit:** I can't decide if this is a correct implementation because I don't know what algorithm you are trying to implement. But you only asked:

> Why are the numbers decreasing if the i isn't used at all at the function?

Comment: Better to use `for _ in range(5)` since `i` is never used

Comment: Oh I see! So at first I have x=1 but after the first loop it the x equals 1.5, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the result of the first call to `heron`. `1.5` is assigned to  `x` and used in the 2nd call.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement [Heron's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to find the root square of a number.

It is an iterative algorithm where you increase precision of the result at each step.

In your implementation, `x` is an initial solution and `y` is the number you want to find the root square.

You are doing `5` iterations and the variable `i` is not required to do your iterations. You can use `_` to declare a non needed variable.

You could define a wanted precision and iterate a various number of times to reach the wanted precision.

```
def heron(x,y):
    x=(x+y/x)*0.5
    return x

x=1
y=2
numberOfIterations = 5
for _ in range(numberOfIterations):
    x=heron(x,y)
    print('Approximation of square root : %.16f'%x)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you must modify your code as follow :-

```
def heron(x,y):
    x=(x+y/x)*0.5
    return x

x=1
y=2
for i in range(5):
   z=heron(x,y)
   print 'Approximation of square root :%.16f'%z
```